# Make a link Hide after one click in RoR

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using ryanb's simple_nested_form and i have the following Code

```
<%= f.link_to_add "Shipping Address", :shipping_addresses %>
```

I want this link to be executed only once and then it should hide. I believe i should use jquery or ajax but i don't know much about ajax/jquery. Can anyone suggest how i can make this Link execute only once? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all download jQuery from www.jquery.com. Next add the JS  file to your page.
The next thing should be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascrip>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#your_link_id").click(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

That's about it. If you want to hide every anchor that is clicked replace #your_link_id with a as in $("a"). Also, if you anchor tag has some class, you can hide it based on its class, like $("a.myClass").

UPDATE:

In relation to your comment, a code might look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a:not(.clickedOnce)").click(function() {
        $(this)
            .addClass("clickedOnce")   
            .on("click", function()     
                { 
                    $(this).hide();   
                });
       });
});
```

Basically, when you click on a link a class named *clickedOnce* will be added. After that with you use .on() to tell this link to hide itself on second click.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Here is the sample how this works: http://jsfiddle.net/rvQ4w/23/

Comment: Thanks buddy. its working But is it possible to make this link hide the second time? Sorry i wasnt clear in the question. The link is connected to a partial. So I want the link to execute once and Then Hide.

Comment: So, you want to click the link, display something, click second time on it and then hide it?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i want!

Comment: @bharath - I think I figured it out. Took some doing, but it's an easy fix once it's all worked out.

Comment: @bharath - I'm confused, so you want the link to not hide until they've clicked it a second time?  Or you want it to actually work on the first click and hide once whatever displays from the click shows up?

Comment: @Anthony, bharath wants to click once on a link, and then on the second click to hide it. It was clarified in a previous comment, and the above solution actually does the job.

Comment: @Anthony- Yeah, Click once execute it, then on Second click execute it

Comment: @Huske - it was the clarification that confused me. I guess I'm just having trouble imagining a use case where the user will know or be inclined to click on a link a second time just to make that link disappear.  I guess if it also makes the generated content disappear?

Comment: @Huske- The hide function seems to be working on all the links in my app and i want this functionality to work only with that link. What do i do?

Comment: If the link that should be hidden has an ID or some specific class then replace $("a:not(.clickedOnce)") with something like $("#my_anchor_id:not(.clickedOnce)"). Give your anchor an ID value so that you can apply this script to that one specific anchor.

Answer (score 1):

To get the link to actually fire when using the `hide` method, you have to include a callback in the `hide()` method to return true, which will bubble up to the original event callback. My tests with just returning true in the main function didn't work, so I think the `hide` method must short-circuit any event propagation. Since you want it to fire only after they've clicked it the second time, you would want to bind the `click` event twice, the first click calls the function that binds any following click events on that element to the `hide` method. Basically just a second layer.

```
$("a").on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

If you don't want the second-click to actually fire the primary event the second time (like if you have it make text display, but on second click, you don't want the text to re-display), you should unbind the primary event, like so:

```
$("a").on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).unbind(e);
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Anthony the link is getting Hidden on first link, want it to execute once and then it should get hidden the second time.May can modify this to get it hide the second time. Thanks in advance.